# Why is minus going after the numbers when I convert the number in the string?

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, nasm, number-formatting

I have written the code on Netwide Assembler that converts an integer to a string but console's output is wrong. And if it will help I write code on Windows 10 under x64 architecture.

I tried to write a procedure *_int_to_string* but I get other output in the console.

```
section .bss
    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE: equ -11
    char_written: resb 1
    buffer: resb 32

section .text
    extern GetStdHandle
    extern WriteConsoleA
    extern ExitProcess

    global _start

    _print:
        sub rsp, 40

        mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE          
        call GetStdHandle                   ;returns value for handle to rax

        mov rcx, rax
        mov r9, char_written

        mov rax, qword 0                    ;fifth argument
        mov qword [rsp+32], rax

        call WriteConsoleA
        add rsp, 40
        ret
    
    _start:
        mov rcx, buffer
        mov rdx, -24567789
        call _int_to_string

        mov rdx, rax
        mov rcx, rax
        call _len
        mov r9, rax
        call _print

        mov rcx, qword 0
        call ExitProcess
    _int_to_string: ; this procedure uses rcx, rdx, r8 register. Keep this in mind
        mov r8, 10
        mov rax, rdx
        cmp rdx, 0
        jns T1
        neg rdx
        mov byte [rcx], '-'
        dec rcx
        mov rax, rdx
        T1:
            xor     rdx,rdx
            div     r8
            add     rdx, 48              ; convert the digit to ASCII
            mov     BYTE [rcx], dl   ; store the character in the buffer
            dec     rcx                 ; decrement ecx pointing the buffer
            test    rax,rax             ; check if the quotient is 0
            jnz     T1
        inc     rcx
        mov     rax, rcx            ; eax points the string in the buffer
        ret
    _len:
        cmp byte [rcx], 0
        jz  lpend
        inc rcx
        jmp _len
    lpend:
        sub rcx, rdx
        mov rax, rcx
        ret
```

And console's output is "24567789-".
As you understood I expected this output: "-24567789".
I am beginner in assembly language so I don't know what I should do. And sorry if my English is bad. It is not my native language, I learn it.
All my tools: NASM x64, golink, console, visual studio code.

Answer (score 2):

- You are building your number **from right to left**. If you want to have the minus sign on the left of the number, then don't immediately output it, but postpone until all digits have been stored.
  You can use `pushf` to preserve the outcome from comparing the number to zero (something you can do using the `test` instruction).
- Your code was also overflowing the 32-byte buffer to the left! If you are going to work with **decreasing addresses**, then start high up in the buffer (not at its lowest address).

```
; IN (rdx,rcx)
_int_to_string: ; uses rcx, rdx, r8 register. Keep this in mind
  add  rcx, 32     ; Begin at the end of the buffer
  mov  r8d, 10     ; CONST
  mov  rax, rdx
  test rax, rax
  pushf            ; (1)
  jns  T1
  neg  rax

T1:
  dec  rcx         ; Position for the following digit
  xor  edx, edx
  div  r8
  add  edx, 48     ; convert the digit to ASCII
  mov  [rcx], dl   ; store the character in the buffer
  test rax, rax    ; check if the quotient is 0
  jnz  T1

  popf             ; (1)
  jns  T2
  dec  rcx
  mov  byte [rcx], '-'
T2:
  mov  rax, rcx    ; RAX points the string in the buffer
  ret
```